# Python: can I use a class-level decorator to add a mixin to the decorated class?

Tags: python, decorator, superclass

I'd like to have a decorator that, among other stuff, adds a mixin to the class it's decorating. (I recognize that this may be a Really Bad Idea but bear with me.) The following almost works:

```
def add_mixin(cls):
   class inner(cls, NewMixin):
      pass
   return inner
```

Now if I do:

```
@add_mixin
class foo:
   ...bunch o' stuff...
```

class `foo` seems to work just fine, with `NewMixin` mixed in. (Maybe this scheme wouldn't exactly preserve the MRO of `foo` in the face of other superclasses but I don't think I care about that.)

The only problem I've found is that at this point `foo.__name__` is `"inner"` and I'd like it to be `"foo"`! I can work around this by adding
`inner.__name__ = cls.__name__` in the definition of `add_mixin` and that seems to cover all the bases (as it were).

Question: Is there a better way to do this? Are there other lurking pitfalls here that I'm not seeing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit of using a decorator over adding the mixin directly. It's simpler, and doesn't add a meaningless wrapper class to the MRO.

Comment: Did you try explicitly patching it in the new class?

Comment: @chepner I assume (hope) that the decorator is intended to do more than *just* add the mixin, but that adding the mixin is the part of the code relevant to the question.

Comment: The "among other stuff" is probably what makes the question interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: The question was edited to mention this approach while I was writing the answer.*

You can do:

```
def add_mixin(cls):
   class inner(cls, NewMixin):
      pass
   inner.__name__ = cls.__name__
   return inner
```

and then:

```
@add_mixin
class foo:
   pass

@add_mixin
class bar:
   pass

f = foo
print(f.__name__)
b = bar
print(b.__name__)
print(f.__name__)
```

gives

```
foo
bar
foo
```

(Printing foo a second time after referencing bar to demonstrate that __name__ isn't overwritten.)

In terms of pitfalls, that I'm not sure about.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this too late and added it myself just as you were writing your comment. Note that there's no need for an added variable i, you can just say inner.__name__ = cls.__name__. Also note that you *can't* do it inside the definition of inner: Just saying __name__ = cls.__name__ doesn't work; don't know why.

Comment: Oh right, because you can still just return inner. I'll make the tweak so the answer is a bit neater, though it's not that useful of an answer anymore :) My first attempt was just trying to set \_\_name__ directly, but it didn't work as you mentioned.

Comment: I have accepted your answer since it's the right one. However, I have since indeed discovered a pitfall which I'm going to put in another question. I'll come back here and supply a pointer when I've got that done.